# Salesforce not honoring prompt option

Tags: node.js, heroku, oauth-2.0, salesforce, passport.js

I have a node app which uses passport-forcdotcom strategy for user login. I am using the `prompt: 'login'` option as following

```
app.get('/auth/salesforce', passport.authenticate('forcedotcom', {prompt: 'login'}));
```

When I run this app on my local development machine, salesforce always prompts for user login.

But when I deploy the app to heroku (which uses different SFDC connected app), this does not happen and salesforce redirects to callback URL without prompting for user login.

I have also tried after revoking the token on logout but still the same issue.

Both salesforce apps, use same scope permissions

What am I missing or should do to achieve login prompt on the heroku server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that both options are required to make this work, once I added the `display: 'page'` option, everything started working as expected

```
app.get('/auth/salesforce', 
    passport.authenticate('forcedotcom', {display: 'page', prompt: 'login'})
);
```